# Syntax error in the code creating a PostgreSQL procedure

Tags: postgresql, syntax-error

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
    Cree_RefFacture() 
RETURNS trigger 
AS 
$BODY$ 
    BEGIN 
        NEW."RefFacture" := nextval("dbo.Base_Factures_RefFacture_seq"); 
        RETURN NEW; 
    END; 
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I get syntax error on this line :

> ```
> Syntax error on or near “NEW” 
> LINE 7:NEW."RefFacture":=nextval"dbo.Base_Factures_RefFacture_seq");
> ```

Something wrong in your opinion?

I've tried various solutions, I keep getting the same error. Could you help me please

Comment: this one could be fine, but you left out the rest of your code. Minor advice: Never ever use UPPER case in your object names, this will cause problems. Even if you try to use double quotes everywhere, you will forget it somewhere. I'm already having doubts about "dbo.Base Factures_RefFacture_seq", are you sure dbo is part of the name or is the schema?

Comment: I'm going to say it should be `nextval("dbo"."Base Factures_RefFacture_seq")`. Though without the rest of the  code and the error message it is just a guess.

Comment: 1) Add the code to your question text properly formatted. 2) You have not included the error message. Add that to the question also.

Comment: There is no problem with this code, works fine. It's kind of strange, a default value in your table could do the same as this trigger function, just simpler.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Cree_RefFacture()
   RETURNS trigger AS
 $BODY$`
BEGIN
     NEW."RefFacture" := nextval("dbo.Base_Factures_RefFacture_seq"); 
     RETURN NEW;
END; 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql; 

Syntax error on or near “NEW” LINE 7:NEW."RefFacture":=nextval"dbo.Base_Factures_RefFacture_seq");

Comment: Yes, dbo is a correct schema

Comment: RefFacture is a primary key, I can't give it a default value

Comment: @DanEd Please share the DDL of your table, because using a default for your primary key is pretty standard. And please share this information as an update of your question, not as a comment.

Comment: @DanEd default value doesn't have to be static, the same for all new rows. It can be dynamically generated: [`create table test(id int default nextval('some_sequence') primary key);`](https://dbfiddle.uk/mJoZyjaj) - that's perfectly legal. You can even offload the process of setting up the sequence and tying it to the table and column if you follow [Frank Heikens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77761740/5298879) and set up an [automatically generated identity column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-GENERATED-IDENTITY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a trigger and trigger function to get an id for a primary key. Just use an identity column and you will be fine.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
    id_t1 INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    content TEXT
);

INSERT INTO t1(content)
VALUES ('my content'), ('some other content')
RETURNING id_t1;

SELECT * FROM t1;
```